# Best way to pass parent methods as props to grandchild components?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, redux

I have a grandchild component that needs to change the state of a parent component. 
What is the best way to change the state of the of the parent component from an onClick of a grandchild component?

React docs mentions using context to access methods. Is there people that have used that successfully to pass methods to grandchildren?

The way I am doing it is passing the parent component method via props to the child. Then creating a new method in the child that calls the parent method and passing that child method to the grandchild via props. This method is then called on the grandchild and cascades up to the parent to set the state of the parent.

Do i need to restructure my components so I don't have so many nested components? What is the best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question : "Is it used by developers ?" : yes (routers or flux providers for ex. pass methods by context that get used by child components) - or "How can I do this ?"

Comment: You don't have to create new you can pass down as-is.  [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) gives the exact example using context also.  But it is warned against for possible deprecation / unstability of API.

Comment: I had concerns over this exact issue as well and in the end went with passing `this.setState` to children as a prop. Works very well and makes code much less cluttered. Probably there is a better way with flux/context/etc but I didn't investigate the deeply.

Comment: @aarosil For some reasons it was giving me problems in the past, but you are totally right. You can pass down props without creating a new method to wrap the other in. I tried it again and it worked great.

Comment: Passing methods down as props can make understanding data flow more difficult and frail. Have you checked out [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/)?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I am using Redux currently. What aspect of the Flux Architecture do you think I could benefit from?

Comment: @gkkirsch I consider Redux Flux-ish, so what I'll say applies equally to both. There are certainly edge cases where passing down methods is most expeditious and sustainable, but more often I find that using actions is better. They tend to create a cleaner data flow, make components more independent and decoupled, and simplify unit testing. It's needing to pass to *grand*children that makes me think there is likely a better way.